# Hadoop fs -get copy only specific files

Tags: hadoop

Is there a way to copy only specific files, say based on file type using fs -get or fs -copyToLocal? Note: I would like this to be recursive and traverse the entire cluster.

Figured it out but I can't answer my own question.

Here's how we did it. Just wrote a quick shell script.

```
mkdir /tmp/txt

    for F in `hadoop fs -fs hdfs://namenode.mycluster -lsr / | grep '/*.txt$' | awk '{print $NF}'; 
    do
       hadoop fs -fs hdfs://namenode.mycluster -copyToLocal $F /tmp/las/ 
    done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how we did it. Just wrote a quick shell script.

```
LOCAL_DIR=/tmp/txt
mkdir $LOCAL_DIR

for F in `hadoop fs -fs hdfs://namenode.mycluster -lsr / | grep '/*.txt$' | awk '{print $NF}'; 
do
   hadoop fs -fs hdfs://namenode.mycluster -copyToLocal $F $LOCAL_DIR 
done`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give regular expression to copy files. there is an example here to use command line in hadoop. This does not uses get, but it uses put, which should behave same as get.

Something like this : `hadoop fs -get out/*`

http://prazjain.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/how-to-run-hadoop-map-reduce-program-from-command-line/

Comment: While this would work i'm trying to do it recursively. Sorry for not specifying that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop doesn't support the double-star glob notation in paths, so there is no out-of the box way of doing this:

```
hadoop fs -get /**/*.txt /tmp
```

You can however write your own code to do it - look into the current source for FsShell, and pair that with FileInputFormat's listStatus method - which can be configured to accept a PathFilter. In this PathFilter you can only return true if the Path is of the file type you desire.