# Processing multiple files in HDFS via Python

Tags: python, hadoop, scripting, hdfs

I have a directory in HDFS that contains roughly 10,000 .xml files. I have a python script "processxml.py" that takes a file and does some processing on it. Is it possible to run the script on all of the files in the hdfs directory, or do I need to copy them to local first in order to do so?

For example, when I run the script on files in a local directory I have:

```
cd /path/to/files

for file in *.xml
do
python  /path/processxml.py 
$file > /path2/$file
done
```

So basically, how would I go about doing the same, but this time the files are in hdfs?

Comment: Can you modify the processxml.py file? You could use the python hdfs package: http://hdfscli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#reading-and-writing-files which allows you access to the files without needing to store them on your disk as an intermediate step, but unless you can modify your xml processor it probably wont help you.

Comment: Yes actually, I can modify the .py file, I will read the documentation..thanks @TomDalton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1) Use hadoop streaming connector to create a MapReduce job (here you will only need the map part). Use this command from the shell or inside a shell script:

```
hadoop jar <the location of the streamlib> \
        -D mapred.job.name=<name for the job> \
        -input /hdfs/input/dir \
        -output /hdfs/output/dir \
        -file your_script.py \
        -mapper python your_script.py \
        -numReduceTasks 0
```

2) Create a PIG script and ship your python code. Here is a basic example for the script:

```
input_data = LOAD '/hdfs/input/dir';
DEFINE mycommand `python your_script.py` ship('/path/to/your/script.py');
updated_data = STREAM input_data THROUGH mycommand PARALLEL 20;    
STORE updated_data INTO 'hdfs/output/dir';
```

Comment: So it is not possible to just access the files in HDFS one at a time and run the py code on them? Something similar to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686625/hadoop-fs-get-copy-only-specific-files)? @Javier

Comment: Also, are you missing semi-colons in the PIG example? @Javier

Comment: Yeah. Some semi-colon were missing. Corrected

Comment: Currently it just dumps all of the data together into the output dir. Is there a way to group the output data into its own .xml file for each input .xml file? @Javier

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process data in your files or move/cp/rm/etc. them around the file-system then PySpark (Spark with Python interface) would be one of the best options (speed, memory).