# how to pass subprocess object to array

Tags: python, object, hadoop, subprocess

1. I need to pass the subprocess object to an array, so I can process the contents of the path.
2. here is my code
3. under "/file/path" the content is as such:
   id1 name1 location1 hive    1 2014-10-01 4:02 /file/path

   ```
   p = subprocess.Popen(["hdfs", "dfs", "-ls", "/file/path"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   result = p.communicate()[0]
   path = []
   p = path.append(result)
   ```

   but when I print p, it returns "None"        ,so what can I do if I need to pass the contents to an array, can I even do that in python?
   Thanks!

Comment: btw, my python version is 2.6 so I cannot use check_output module

Comment: I think `path.append(result)` doesn't return anything that may be the reason you are getting `None`

Comment: Are you trying to pass an array of arguments to a subprocess or are you actually trying to append the results of the execution of a subprocess to an array?

Comment: I am trying to append the results of the execution of a subprocess to an array, so I can process the contents of the array.

Comment: OK, I am not sure if you are using sample code in the example that you give, but one problem that I see is the line:
```python
p = path.append(result)
```
path.append has no return value so that assignment will set p to None.

Comment: I understand that but the result variable has return from the subprocess argument

Comment: I've added an example of what it is I think that you are trying to do below, but just to be clear you DO NOT want to assign the return result of path.append to a variable, because it will ALWAYS be NONE. All you have to do is `path.append(result). The variable p contains your subprocess object.

It looks like you are trying to parallelize some process that operates on some set of files using Hadoop and Python if that is indeed the case, I would recommend the approach described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070998/processing-multiple-files-in-hdfs-via-python

Comment: @Michelle You could try `p = results.splitlines()` **Note:** As its a scripting language it will re-assign p with `Array of strings` which will result in loss of subprocess object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the results of the screen output from the command `hdfs dfs -ls /some/path` is going to be a string. If your intention is to actually obtain file names you'll have to parse that string. If you want to add those paths to an array that contains the path a cheap way to do that is:

```
import subprocess
base_dir = "/user/root/input"  # NOTE: This is my hdfs path, yours may differ
p = subprocess.Popen(["hdfs", "dfs", "-ls", base_dir], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.communicate()[0]
lines = result.splitlines()
paths = [word.strip() for word in ' '.join(line for line in lines).split(' ') if base_dir in word]
```

**Output**

```
print paths
# ['/user/root/input/file1.txt', '/user/root/input/file2.txt']
```

**CAUTION** This is a hacky way of doing this, but it should do what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi aquil, your code above just printed out the "/file/path" as list. what I want to print out is the contents from the path not the name of the path. I was able to nail down the list of the string of the contents close to the part that I want.. but still not yet..

Comment: @Michelle I'm not sure what you are talking about. Do you want to print the contents of the files in a particular path or do you want to print the filenames under a particular path?  I made an edit to the code above, but here is the output from my simple example an a hadoop cluster that I setup just for this example:


    >>> paths
    ['/user/root/input/file1.txt', '/user/root/input/file2.txt']

Does your hdfs directory have any files under /file/path? Could you give me an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: thank you! it is very close, I just need to grab the timestamps from that result  to do further operations! thanks!